# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' angular

Tags: angular, mapbox, package.json, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I am implementing [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) in angular application and am doing as follows

added css into angular-cli.json

`"../node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css"`

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  static t;
  ngOnInit() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'Token';
    AppComponent.t.map= new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-78.880453, 42.897852]
    });

     const draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        }
    });
    AppComponent.t.map.addControl(draw);
  }
}
```

Its displaying Failed to compile

`./node_modules/jsonlint-lines/lib/jsonlint.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\angular\mapboxdemo\node_modules\jsonlint-lines\lib'`

Below is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mapboxdemo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw": "^1.0.9",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.46.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

I tried to executing `ng eject` command to generate webpack.config file and tried to add { fs: "empty" } but throwing below error

[image]

how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you using webpack? If so, add the following to your config.

node: {
   fs: "empty"
}

Comment: no.. am not using. i used angular cli for setup

Comment: can you post the content of your package.json?

Comment: @EricYang I posted

Comment: Do you have an angular.json or an angular-cli.json file in your directory?

Comment: i had latest version of angular cli and i uninstalled it and installed `1.7.4`.. i have `angular.json`

Comment: Copy to angular.json to angular-cli.json and see if you can eject

Comment: not able to eject `Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.`

Comment: downgrading the angular-cli to 1.7.4 resolved the error..

Comment: Adding "browser": { "fs": false } in package.json solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open `package.json` file, add this into browser object.

```
  "browser": {
     "fs": false,
     "path": false,
     "os": false}
```

If your module is meant to be used client-side the browser field should be used instead of the main field. This is helpful to hint users that it might rely on primitives that aren't available in Node.js modules.

Source: [npm Docs | package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json)

Comment: i tried to add the above browser object to package.json but no luck!